# What's the difference between Windows Dev-Center and Microsoft Developer Network pages?

Tags: msdn

Often times when I search MSDN, I get results from either of those two pages:

- [Windows Dev-Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/)
- [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us)

Both of those pages appear to contain articles from the 'same' MSDN library. What's the difference between those two pages / why are they split like that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have understood from my experience:

- `MSDN` is more of a social platform which Microsoft uses to build a relationship with developers, engineers around the world; It is surely Microsoft centric but *not* Windows specific.

  For e.g. I have read articles in MSDN magazines which were related to general programming problems, C++, Developer blogs etc.
- `Windows Dev-Center`, on other hand is something that emerged after Microsoft introduced Windows 8, it is purely Windows Centric (Phone & Desktop) focusing developers related to these platform.

  As stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/06/08/the-windows-8-dev-center-everything-you-need-to-design-build-and-sell-a-metro-style-app.aspx)

  *The Windows 8 Dev Center: Everything you need to design, build, and sell a Metro style app*

Key thing to note is Windows Dev Center also resides on the domain of `MSDN` itself > *`msdn`.microsoft.com/en-us/`windows`/*